# Angular button does not show, shows on refresh

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

I have an angular controller and a view. The controller code is as follows:

```js
app.controller('someController',
     ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'someService',
     function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, someService) {
 
 $scope.dataLoadingComplete = false;
    $scope.hasStarted = true;

 function getSurvey() {
  $rootScope.loadingView = true;
  someService.getSurvey().then(
     function (results) {
    $rootScope.loadingView = false;
    $scope.dataLoadingComplete = true;
    
    if (results.status === 200) {
     //set other scope variables...
                                                       
                   $scope.totalAnsweredQuestions = results.data.totalAnsweredQuestions;
                    if ($scope.totalAnsweredQuestions > 0)
            $scope.hasStarted = true;
           else
            $scope.hasStarted = false;                                   
        }
     },
     function (error) {
   //log error
   $rootScope.loadingView = false;
   $scope.dataLoadingComplete = true;
       
   $scope.errorMessage = "Error occurred.";

     });
 }
 getSurvey();

}]);
```

In the view I have following code:

```html
<div>
  <p>Some content....</p>
  <div ng-show="dataLoadingComplete">
      <button ng-if="!hasStarted">Start Survey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting issues were some of the users don't see the button to Start Survey.

Comment: 'ng-if="!hasStarted"' can you remove that and test

Comment: I have to show different buttons based on "hasStarted" condition

<div>
  <p>Some content....</p>
  <div ng-show="dataLoadingComplete">
      <button ng-if="!hasStarted">Start Survey</button>
      <button ng-if="hasStarted">Finish Survey</button>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Just remove it for Test purpose

Comment: I don't always face this issue of button "Start Survey" bot showing. Random users of my app are not seeing this button. So, if I remove the condition for testing, it's always going to work for me. I have tested this before w/o any issues.

Comment: Any console log errors?

Answer (score 1):

Verify they aren't getting a response other than 200, or $scope.totalAnsweredQuestions of 0 for those clients.  If you console.log out inside of the if ($scope.totalAnsweredQuestions > 0)   and they still do not see the button, then try and identify a difference in their client hardware (slower machine, perhaps a race condition on the service responding and client rendering page) or a difference in the client browser (they are using browser X and you are using Y)

Comment: They're using iphone, which uses safari browser. I tried the same on my iphone, no issues on my side. I am guessing it could be that there internet connection is slow or something. But, even in that case it should show after a delay right?